# How to Configure Routes of Scaffold Generator in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble with configuring the model which is generated by scaffold in my Rails 4 application.

These are my models:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :contact

    after_create :make_contact
    def make_contact
      create_contact(
       :country => "USA",
       :city => "Newyork"
      )
    end
end
```

As you can see, I'm creating a Profile model instance for each User when they registered for the site.

**I generated User model with Devise GEM and generated Contact model with rails scaffold generator.**

1) I want my Users to only update or view their profile. I want to prevent them to list all profiles, destroy their profiles or create a new profile. What is the best approach to do this?

2) I want my application to redirect automatically to the users related profile page when they visit /contacts route.

3) User can't be able to see other users profiles by changing the URL like /contacts/1, contacts/2 etc.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What your asking is exactly why you should use Devise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `before_filter/before_action` in your controller

```
def UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :restrict_user, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]

 private
 def restrict_user
   redirect_to :root, :alert => "Not authorized" unless params[:id] = current_user.id
 end
end
```

In your routes, you can specify only the actions that you want

```
resources :users, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show] #index and destroy are not in the list
```

You can do the same in contacts controller too